# polynomial addition using array of terms

Tags: arrays

I am trying to create a program that can add two polynomials that are stored in an array. Each term of a polynomial(coefficient and exponent) is stored as one index in an array(I have a term class that does this).
When I call my add method, it's not always combining coefficients that have the same exponents.

```
public Polynomial add(Polynomial p1, Polynomial p2)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int newin = 0; //index or location of new terms being stored for Polynomial p3
    Polynomial p3 = new Polynomial();


    while (i<p1.TermLength || j<p2.TermLength)
    {


           if (i==p1.TermLength)
            {
                p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p2.poly[j].getCoeff());
                p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p2.poly[j].getExpo());
                j++;    // j is increased whenever a term from Poly2 has been utilized
           }

         else if (j==p2.TermLength)
            {
                p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p1.poly[i].getCoeff());
                p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p1.poly[i].getExpo());
                i++;    // i is increased by 1 whenever a term from Poly1 has been utilized
           }

         else if (p1.poly[i].getExpo()>p2.poly[j].getExpo())
            {
               p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p1.poly[i].getCoeff());
                p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p1.poly[i].getExpo());
                i++;
            }

         else if (p1.poly[i].getExpo()<p2.poly[j].getExpo())
            {
                p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p2.poly[j].getCoeff());
                p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p2.poly[j].getExpo());
                j++;
            }                             
         else if (p1.poly[i].getExpo() == p2.poly[j].getExpo())
         {
            p3.poly[newin].setExpo(p1.poly[i].getExpo());
            p3.poly[newin].setCoeff(p1.poly[i].getCoeff() + p2.poly[j].getCoeff());
            i++;
            j++;
         }  

         newin++;


    }


    p3.TermLength = p3.poly.length;

    return p3;
}
```

Comment: My last condition adds the 2 coefficients if the exponents are alike. How would I create a loop that goes through my Polynomial after a Term has already be assigned? Maybe there's a more efficient way to go about this.

Comment: pls post an example of the array you want to use.

Comment: For example:(2.0x + 1.0x^2) + (2.0x^2) the output will be 2.0x^2 + 2.0x + 1.0x^2

Comment: sorry i don't get it...maybe my math is weak but it could have to be: (2x + x^2) + 2x^2 ... and finally x (3 x+2) ...or not?

Comment: It would be. However, my last comment contains what my output currently is. If the last argument else if (p1.poly[i].getExpo() == p2.poly[j].getExpo()) is true, then it combines the terms and puts it in the array but it doesn't take into account if a term with the same exponent comes up again

Comment: well...it seems a sort of "semplifier", on other words, it gaves you the terms ready to be added. 
If i understand well i could arrange something for you. It is a very interesting project.

Comment: Would uploading the rest of the program help?

Comment: no thanks i'll make by myself...i hope to find time in the week end pal!